# Dynamically create a new object from a class with different namespace

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I'm trying to create a small RESTful API for my database and I encountered a problem creating controller object dynamically based on user request, because all my code is using namespaces and just doing:

```
$api = new $controllerName($request);
```

Won't work. Because `$controllerName` would resolve to "ReadController", but is actually `\controllers\lottery\ReadController` hence the error

The whole part of defining the path to the class is:

```
if ($method === 'GET') {
    $controllerName = 'ReadController';
    // @NOTE: $category is a part of $_GET parameters, e.g: /api/lottery <- lottery is a $category
    $controllerFile = CONTROLLERS.$category.'/'.$controllerName.'.php';
    if (file_exists($controllerFile)) {
        include_once($controllerFile);

        $api = new $controllerName($request);
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('Undefined controller');
    }
}
```

And the declaration of ReadController in core\controllers\lottery\ReadController.php

```
namespace controllers\lottery;

class ReadController extends \core\API {

}
```

Any ideas how to dynamically create the object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$controllerName = 'controllers\lottery\ReadController';
new $controllerName($request);
```

Classes instantiated from strings must always use the *fully qualified class name*.

Comment: That simple... damn.. Thanks, it worked. Will accept the answer in 10min.

Comment: Yes, I had similar problem. The only improvement to answer is: _why_ it is so. And it's so because PHP will replace namespace aliases to it's full path on interpretation, so aliases will not persist in opcodes and VM will know nothing of them

Comment: @Alma I think that's way too detailed an explanation. It's as simple as http://stackoverflow.com/a/16808358/476

Comment: Fair enought. I thought OP was asking about `ReadController` as an alias for `\controllers\lottery\ReadController`