# factory design pattern with dynamic class name

Tags: php, design-patterns, namespaces, factory-pattern

i'm trying to create a factory design pattern that will generate classes with a dynamic class name.

my code:

```
namespace FOO;

class MyFactory {
    public static function create($name) {
        return new \FOO\$name;
    }

}
```

I get a parsing syntax error (as netbeans indicated). is that possible or good practice?
thanks

EDIT:
parsing error: "unexpected variable name after \ expected identifier"

Comment: Well, the syntax error probably is the single double quote in `return new \FOO\$name";` (no match...).

Comment: no...sorry that's a typo. fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To instantiate classes with a variable name, you need to put the entire name, including namespace, into the variable:

```
$name = "Foo\\$name"; // note: no leading backslash
return new $name;
```

Comment: Why no leading backslash? Certainly a class can be referenced by its fully qualified name! In contrary: in the above example your suggestion would lead to a class name of `\FOO\FOO\<name>` ...

Comment: No it wouldn't. Variable class names are always FQN. They are not relative to the current namespace, they always start at the top. It's just the same as not using a leading backslash in `use Foo\Bar` statements, they're always FQN as  well.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I have to try that... Sounds like a strange logic, but it might explain some strange effects I encountered before ;-)

Comment: Basically, the *name* of the class is `Foo\Bar`, so since you instantiate it *by name* using a variable that's what you need. A leading backslash is only for name resolution, which doesn't apply here. :)

Comment: @arkascha woriking great....! but i didnt quite understood the backslash issue..can you please elaborate? (i'm asking because adding backslash also worked)

Comment: @Danny String class names are always fully qualified and do not require a leading backslash. A leading backslash is for signifying "I'm not talking about a class in this namespace, but in another namespace". Since fully qualified names are always "in another namespace", the backslash is not needed/wrong. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808044/using-namespaces-with-classes-created-from-a-variable/16808358#16808358.