# How can we pass a class as a function argument in PHP? Im getting Class 'SomeModel2' not found

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5

To be more specific I want to pass multiple model class of laravel 5.2 via different controller's or class function.

My Model :- SomeModel2.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class SomeModel2 extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'some_table';
    public $timestamps = false;

}
?>
```

My Class where i want to use the model or class as argument :-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests, DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\SomeModel1, App\SomeModel2;
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('admin');
    }

    public function index(){
        return view('admin.admin_home');
    }
    public function logout()
    {
         Auth::logout();
         return redirect('/admin/login');
    }


    public function someFunction1(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('post')) {
                $foo = 'SomeModel1';   /* Here i want to pass different model class to the someFunction2 like someModel1 and someModel2*/

                $this->someFunction2($foo);
            }
        }

    }


    public function someFunction2($foo)
    {
            $obj = new $foo;
    }


}

?>
```

i dont want to pass its instance rather the whole class or model. I have multiple model to pass like someModel1, someModel2, someModel3, someModel4, someModel5

Comment: Usually you hand over the class name, so a string. You can use that string later on to instantiate an object of that class or call static methods in it.

Comment: BTW. your routing seems weird, why would you check the request method instead of proper routing definitions?

Comment: You pretty much have the answer in your code: `$foo = 'SomeModel1'`. You can pass `$foo` around. You can pass it as argument into the function.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16808358/476

Comment: @deceze thanks a lot for answering . i had to use its namespace to pass the class as its argument