# When is "get_class equals" not the same as "instanceof"?

Tags: php

I have some code where:

```
get_class($foo) == Bar::class
```

is not the same as:

```
$foo instanceof Bar::class
```

What possible reasons could this be the case?

Comment: `instanceof` takes care of inheritance.

Comment: so with `get_class`, they have to be exactly the same?

Comment: There's is_a() too.  But in my php version I have to spell out the entire namespaces/class name.  Prefer instanceof, but never remember the syntax.

Comment: @Progrock It's not *your* version of PHP, that's simply how it works. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16808358/476. And `instanceof` is an *operator*, same as `+`, with the same syntax: `A instanceof B`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An object is an `instanceof` a given *C* if it's:

- an object of that exact class *C*
- an object of a class which `extends` the class *C*, or any child thereof
- an object of a class which `implements` the given interface *C*, or any child thereof

`get_class` will only equal the first case, if it's exactly *that* class, because it compares the name of the class, not its heritage. It will not match subclasses or interfaces.